# Injecting Behaviors Before and After Method Execution to log input and output

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have many lines of code like:

```
private SomeOutputModel Method(SomeInputModel model)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug(JsonSerializer.Serialize(model));
        SomeOutputModel result = DoSomething();
        _logger.LogDebug(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));
        return result;
    }
```

practically I need to log the input and output of some methods. I know I should do this in respect to AoP and I know there is some non-free library like PostSharp outside, but I need a hint to create a simple decorator pattern for my methods or delegates to give me this ability to invoke or execute these methods. Hence I would be able to inject any behavior among the functions, but I don't want to use reflection as much as possible because I assume it will make the code meaningless and comparatively slow to original one.

Comment: Afraid of reflection but not afraid to serialize??

Comment: any other way to log the Objects?

Comment: Which ASP.NET Core version are you asking about? In .NET 5 and .NET 6 this is already available through the `System.Diagnostics` namespace and the `Activity` class. Controllers and actions are already instrumented so what you really need is to [configure listening](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/observability-asp-net-core-apps/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach for accomplishing this would be to use something like [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki), which, to quote the author, is *"a low-ambition library trying to solve a simple problem — decoupling the in-process sending of messages from handling messages."*

That decoupling introduces opportunities to create handlers for specific requests types that can be wrapped with a pipeline behavior at a more generic level to cover cross-cutting concerns like logging.

You might create a handler like follows:

```
public class SomeOutputModelHandler : IRequestHandler<SomeInputModel, SomeOutputModel>
{
    private ISomeInterfaceDependency _somethingDoer;

    public ModelHandler(ISomeInterfaceDependency somethingDoer)
    {
        _somethingDoer = somethingDoer;
    }

    public async Task<SomeOutputModel> Handle(SomeInputModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await _somethingDoer.DoSomething(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

This would be invoked by passing the model to Mediatr like: `var outputModel = await mediator.Send(myInputModel);`

At this point, lifting directly from the MediatR wiki, you can register a generic pipeline behavior that covers all of your handler cases that logs everything before and after execution:

> https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors#registering-pipeline-behaviors
>
> ```
> public class LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
> {
>     private readonly ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> _logger;
>
>     public LoggingBehavior(ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger)
>     {
>         _logger = logger;
>     }
>
>     public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
>     {
>         _logger.LogInformation($"Handling {typeof(TRequest).Name}");
>         var response = await next();
>         _logger.LogInformation($"Handled {typeof(TResponse).Name}");
>
>         return response;
>     }
> }
> ```

You can see examples of this request/response behavior including pipelines in the MediatR samples at https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/tree/master/samples/MediatR.Examples

Comment: you made my day, I tested it with a few commands and corresponding handlers and it worked very nice and clean, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Without using reflection, and with the caveat that the "decoration" has to be done on method call instead of on method definition, a simple and basic solution could be:

For each generic Func or Action signature you need, create a corresponding method that would perform the Logging.

Using Serilog (or equivalent), you wouldn't have to do serialization by yourself to log the input and output objects, by leveraging the Serilog @ operator.

Serilog homepage explain briefly the @ operator use, see: https://serilog.net/

Here is how it could be done:

```cs
public static class LogUtils
{
    public static TResult LogDecorate<TSource, TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> method, TSource input)
    {
        Log.Information("{@input1}", input1);
        var result = method(input);
        Log.Information("{@result}", result);
        return result;
    }


    public static TResult LogDecorate<TSource1, TSource2, TResult>(Func<TSource1, TSource2, TResult> Method, TSource1 input1, TSource2 input2)
    {
        Log.Information("{@input1} - {@input2}", input1, input2);
        var result = Method(input);
        Log.Information("{@result}", result);
        return result;
    }
    // Etc...
}
```

Use would be:

```cs
var result = LogUtils.LogDecorate(MyMethod, input);
```

Comment: it wasn't my solution but it reminded me an important feature in Serilog, thanks Laurent